# SymPy: Custom print format for a custom Function expression

Tags: python, sympy

What is the correct way to define classes that inherit the `Function` class in Sympy and create custom print statements for them?

I have followed the examples from https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html that modify the output of `Mod` and it all works fine.

For example:

*With a Custom Printer*

```
from sympy import Symbol, Mod
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter


class MyLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def _print_Mod(self, expr, exp=None):
        return 'hey'


def print_my_latex(expr):
    print(MyLatexPrinter().doprint(expr))


x = Symbol('x')
m = Symbol('m')

print_my_latex(Mod(x, m))

# prints: hey
```

Or

*With a Custom Printing Method*

```
from sympy import Symbol, Mod
from sympy.printing.latex import print_latex


class ModOp(Mod):
    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        return "hello"


x = Symbol('x')
m = Symbol('m')

print_latex(ModOp(x, m))

# prints: hello
```

However when I try to create my own function I can never get either method to alter the output.

*With a Custom Printer*

```
from sympy import Symbol, Function
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter


class MyLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def _print_Custom(self, expr, exp=None):
        return 'hi'


def print_my_latex(expr):
    print(MyLatexPrinter().doprint(expr))


class Custom(Function):

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, a, b):
        return a * b


a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')

print_my_latex(Custom(a, b))

# prints: a b
```

Or

*With a Custom Printing Method*

```
from sympy import Symbol, Function
from sympy.printing.latex import print_latex


class Custom(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, a, b):
        return a * b

    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        return "howdy"


a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')

print_latex(Custom(a, b))

# prints: a b
```

Can someone please help me to understand what it is that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Custom has an eval method, `Custom(a,b)` becomes the Mul, `a*b`. Since it is not an instance of Custom your printer method never gets called. If you rename your eval method `_eval` (to disable it) then the `print_latex(Custom(a, b))` will produce the output "hi".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll admit I can't even remember what I was trying to do at the time I asked it. Once I recall what it was I'll try this out.